# Lease Agreement Typo

Tags: california, landlord, residential-lease

A hypothetical person lives in California, USA and signed a paper lease. The landlord returned the signed lease to the tenant in 10 days. The lease contains the exact schedule for monthly rent payments.

```
January  : $ xxxx.xx
February : $ xxxx.xx
...
December : $ xxxx.xx
```

The landlord made a mistake in the payment schedule for one month resulting in a one time 20% rent decrease in April.

The tenant moved in and started executing the payment plan specified in the lease.

Eventually the landlord caught the error and tried to collect the remaining balance of 20% for that month.

Does the landlord have a legal standing to claim a typo in the signed lease and try to collect the remaining 20% for March?

Comment: Is it a simple typo, like exchanging a 3 for a 2 or something that might be reasonably fat-fingered? Or is it something explicit, like the rent is $1200 and that month was $960?

Comment: @RonBeyer it's definitely the later. $1200 vs $960 is a perfect example. It is very likely a person made an error on a calculator first and then transferred it to the document via typing

Comment: I guess that brings up another question, is there a differing amount each month? Something that can be reasonably calculated (or the calculation is explained elsewhere)?

Comment: @RonBeyer it's like this:  January: A, February B, March C, June - August: D, Sept - December: E. 

A,B,C,D,E are all different

Comment: I get that, but does the rent contract say something like "Rent starts at $x and increases y% per month until the end of the lease", or something similar explaining *why* and *how* the rent is calculated to be different each month? This is common in business leases...

Comment: @RonBeyer nothing of that kind